# com.webMethods.jms.naming.keystore vs com.webMethods.jms.ssl.keystore

Tags: webmethods

We are trying to secure and encrypt the communication between our application and webMethods by using the CA signed certificates. During analysis, we got below parameters to be set as system properties in JBoss 6.4.

Could you please explain the difference between below parameters and which one should be used for configuring?

- `com.webMethods.jms.naming.keystore`
- `com.webMethods.jms.ssl.keystore`

Answer (score 0):

JNDI (which is used to look up arbitrary objects like JMS connection factories, JDBC connection factories, EJBs, etc.) is 100% independent from JMS (which is a messaging API). The JNDI specification and JMS specification are completely different and are implemented in different ways. Therefore, both JNDI and JMS each need their own way to secure their communication. The `com.webMethods.jms.naming.keystore` property is used for securing JNDI communication, and `com.webMethods.jms.ssl.keystore` is used for securing JMS communication.

Comment: Thank you Justin Bertram for clarifying. This helps.

Comment: If you think this answer is helpful and/or correct please mark it as such to help users who have this question in the future. Thanks!